# create full window canvas under wordpress contents

Tags: html, wordpress, canvas

I want to put a canvas demo under wordpress a post the fills the page.

How can include it a canvas under a wordpress post.

I try to add it under visual and text but seems to not work.

Comment: can you give more details and ask a precise question ? Given what you wrote i understand you have trouble with the fullscreen api or with positionning your button on the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Note I'm using wordpress on my own server, **not** on wordpress.com

```
<canvas id="c" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -1;"></canvas>
<script>
var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");
function render() {
  gl.clearColor(Math.random(), 0, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

You might need to make sure the body and html have their css height set to 100%

Comment: Right ! not on wordpress.com posts.